# Unable to connect to a domain

Tags: redhawksdr

Here is the error message I receive every time I try to connect to a local `REDHAWK` domain:

```
Failed to connect
org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0
```

How can I fix this? I tried performing a hard reset of **omniNames** and **omniEvents**, but that did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDE sometimes has issues with launching the REDHAWK_DEV Domain. You can open up a terminal window and type:

```
nodeBooter -D
```

to launch the domain. Afterwards, you should be able to connect in the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming by "hard reset" you are referring to the instructions in Appendix M of the REDHAWK manual (http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainap13.html#x39-570000M.2). If this is the case, look for the omniNames process a couple of second after doing the reset (sometimes it will start up for a few seconds, and then error out: we want to make sure it stays up):

```
$ ps -ef | grep omni
```

If omniNames is not staying up, there are 3 things to look for.

1. Check the logs in /etc/log/omniORB for any errors. Please post any errors that you might find.
2. Verify that /etc/omniORB.cfg is set up incorrectly. Please post your omniORB.cfg file if possible.
3. Make sure the /var partition is not full:

   $ df -h | grep var